# How can I setup Laravel 3 routes for pages of focus on my default controller?

Tags: php, redirect, seo, url-routing, laravel

There will be several high profile links for customers to focus on, for example:

- Contact Us @ domain.com/home/contact
- About the Service @ domain.com/home/service
- Pricing @ domain.com/home/pricing
- How It Works @ domain.com/home/how_it_works

Stuff like that.  I would like to hide the **home** controller from the URL so the customer only sees */contact/*, not */home/contact/*.  Same with */pricing/* not */home/pricing/*

I know I can setup a controller or a route for each special page, but they will look the same except for content I want to pull from the database, and I would rather keep my code DRY.

I setup the following routes:

```
Route::get('/about_us', 'home@about_us');
Route::get('/featured_locations', 'home@featured_locations');
```

Which work well, but I am afraid of SEO trouble if I have duplicate content on the link with the controller in the URL.  ( I don't *plan* on using both, but I have been known to do dumber things.)

So then made routes like these:

```
Route::get('/about_us', 'home@about_us');
Route::get('/home/about_us', function() 
{ 
    return Redirect::to('/about_us', 301);
});

Route::get('/featured_locations', 'home@featured_locations');
Route::get('/home/featured_locations', function() 
{ 
    return Redirect::to('/featured_locations', 301);
});
```

And now I have a redirect.  It feels dumb, but it appears to be working the way I want. If I load the page at my shorter URL, it loads my content.  If I try to visit the longer URL I get redirected.

It is only for about 8 or 9 special links, so I can easily manage the routes, but I feel there must be a smart way to do it.

Is this even an PHP problem, or is this an .htaccess / web.config problem?

What hell have I created with this redirection scheme.  How do smart people do it?  I have been searching for two hours but I cannot find a term to describe what I am doing.

Is there something built into laravel 4 that handles this?

**UPDATE:**

Here is my attempt to implement one of the answers. This is **NOT** working and I don't know what I am doing wrong.

application/routes.php

```
Route::controller('home');

Route::controller('Home_Controller', '/');
```

(you can see the edit history if you really want to look at some broken code)

And now *domain.com/AboutYou* and *domain.com/aboutUs* are returning 404.  But the *domain.com/home/AboutYou* and *domain.com/home/aboutUs* are still returning as they should.

**FINAL EDIT**

I copied an idea from the [PongoCMS routes.php](https://github.com/redbaron76/PongoCMS-Laravel-cms-bundle/blob/master/routes.php) (which is based on Laravel 3) and I see they used filters to get any URI segment and try to create a CMS page.

[See my answer below using route filters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14435311/24229).  This new way doesn't require that I register every special route (good) but does give up redirects to the canonical (bad)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used routes.php and filters to do it.  I copied the idea from the nice looking PongoCMS

https://github.com/redbaron76/PongoCMS-Laravel-cms-bundle/blob/master/routes.php

**application/routes.php**

```
// automatically route all the items in the home controller

Route::controller('home');

// this is my last route, so it is a catch all.  filter it

Route::get('(.*)', array('as' => 'layouts.locations', 'before' => 'checkWithHome', function() {}));

Route::filter('checkWithHome', function()
{
    // if the view isn't a route already, then see if it is a view on the 
    // home controller.  If not, then 404
    $response = Controller::call('home@' . URI::segment(1));
    if ( ! $response )
    {
        //didn't find it
        return Response::error('404');
    }
    else
    {
        return $response;
    }

});
```

<strike>They main problem I see is that the filter basically loads all the successful pages twice.  I didn't see a method in the documentation that would detect if a page exists.  I could probably write a library to do it.</strike>

Of course, with this final version, if I did find something I can just dump it on the page and stop processing the route.  This way I only load all the resources once.

**applicaiton/controllers/home.php**

```
public function get_aboutUs()
{
        $this->view_data['page_title'] = 'About Us';
        $this->view_data['page_content'] = 'About Us';

        $this->layout->nest('content', 'home.simplepage', $this->view_data);
}

public function get_featured_locations()
{
        $this->view_data['page_title'] = 'Featured Locations';
        $this->view_data['page_content'] = 'Featured properties shown here in a pretty row';

        $this->layout->nest('content', 'home.simplepage', $this->view_data);
}

public function get_AboutYou()
{
    //works when I return a view as use a layout
    return View::make('home.index');
}
```

Comment: I will leave it open for a couple days in case somebody comes up with a better answer.

Comment: this looks like Laravel 3 code, very confusing, - or is that from Pongocms?

Comment: @Richard - you are totally right.  See how little I knew.  I was working on the production stuff reading the alpha documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in routes.php:

```
Route::controller('HomeController', '/');
```

This is telling you HomeController to route to the root of the website. Then, from your HomeController you can access any of the functions from there. Just make sure you prefix it with the correct verb. And keep in mind that laravel follows PSR-0 and PSR-1 standards, so methods are camelCased. So you'll have something like:

```
domain.com/aboutUs
```

In the HomeController:

```
<?php

class HomeController extends BaseController 
{
    public function getAboutUs()
    {
        return View::make('home.aboutus');
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't working right away for me.  I am trying to use layouts, so my controllers don't return anything if that matters.  This looks good, so I am poking around trying to get it to fire.

Comment: Also, I don't dispute the PSR-0 or PSR-1 standard, but I am just working through examples so the fewer changes I make from the documents the better.  (For me, for now)

Comment: Sorry, I could not get this to work at all.  I think my install is still pretty out of the box.

Comment: I'm a little late to this, but the parameters are backwards on the Route::controller. The first param is your mapping, the second is the controller to handle the mapping in a RESTful way.